# Virtualbox 7 - How to change motherboard serial number so Windows 10 will recognize it?

Tags: windows-10, serial-number

I'm running Virtualbox 7 on Windows 10 64 bit OS. I have used default settings and created Windows 10 64 bit Education VM. The default serial number is 0 and I need to change this.

I have tried these commands.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "AutopilotTest" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiBoardSerial" "String:Serial1234"

VBoxManage setextradata "AutopilotTest" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial" "Serial1234"
```

But the serial number is always 0.

```
New-Item -Type Directory -Path "C:\HWID"
Set-Location -Path "C:\HWID"
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts"
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo
Get-WindowsAutopilotInfo -OutputFile AutopilotHWID.csv
```

returns

```
Gathered details for device with serial number: 0
```

Same with command 'wmic bios get serialnumber'

When VM is started line DmiSystemSerial is removed from a config file AutopilotTest.vbox. ExtraData is modified to

```
<ExtraData>
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="1024,768"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="1455,280,1024,808"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiBoardSerial" value="String:Serial1234"/>
</ExtraData>
```

**Additional info:**

Command

```
$ VBoxManage setextradata VM-name \
"VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial"      "System Serial"
```

is specified in the official documentation but VirtualBox will remove this from the .vbox file.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/7.0/admin/AdvancedTopics.html#changedmi

**Additional info 2:**

I tested EFI mode and set both those serials as BIOS and EFI. Those settings are found in .vbox file but these all are removed when WM starts.

```
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardSerial" value="SERIAL1234"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial" value="SERIAL1234"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiBoardSerial" value="SERIAL1234"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial" value="SERIAL1234"/>
```

**Additional info 2:**

VirtualBox version 7.0.4 r154605 (Qt5.15.2)
7.0.4 r154605

**Additional info 3:**

Works in version 7.0.14.

PowerShell commans to check the serial number.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_bios | select Serialnumber
```

Comment: Is your virtual machine using BIOS or EFI ?

Comment: BIOS which is the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle's
[Configuring the BIOS DMI Information](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/changedmi.html),
the correct syntax is :

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM-name \
"VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial"      "String:1234"
```

Comment: `string` is needed if the value is not recognized as a string. This command will add DmiSystemSerial to the .vbox file but VirtualBox removes this when VM is started.

Comment: If the VM is EFI and not BIOS, you should use `VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial`. Try also as parameter just "1234".

Comment: I doesn't matter how you set DmiSystemSerial or do you test BIOS or EFI VM. VirtualBox will remove the DmiSystemSerial from .vbox file and the serial number is default 0.

Comment: Finally this works in version 7.0.14.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this.  The "String:12345" parameter has to have a CAPITAL 'S' in the word string.  Then it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).